# google charts how to have 2 graphs from my google sheet

Tags: charts

i have a sheet : 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TXQ-PAfRS5vnRlaO34fYVp4LhyMBHp7MTr2emcSawhk/pubhtml

i need to create 2 graphs in my web page ? what is the solution ? is it possible ?
graph 1 combo charts range A1:C5
b2 to b5 : column
c2 to c5 : line

graph 2 combo charts range A11:C16
b13 to b16 : column
c13 to c16 : line

my code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

        function initialize() {
            // removed the `var opts...` line
            var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TXQ-PAfRS5vnRlaO34fYVp4LhyMBHp7MTr2emcSawhk/edit#gid=1941533272');

            query.send(handleQueryResponse);
        }

        function handleQueryResponse(response) {
            if (response.isError()) {
                alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
                return;
            }

            var data = response.getDataTable();
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            //var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, is3D: true});
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
```

many thanks for your help